# Social Buttons stuck to middle

Tags: html, css

So basically i want my Social Bar to be on the Right side of the Screen yet i just can't figure out why it wont move :(

Tried to mess with the Icon Bar and shiz but im still learning so i don't really know what to do

HTML

```
.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(196, 44, 44);
}

.twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}
```

CSS

```
 <!-- Social Buttons  -->
    <div class="icon-bar">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com//" target="_blank" class="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in//" target="_blank" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code of css:

```
.icon-bar {
 position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

The top value of -100% in icon-bar selector is causing issue in your code. By setting the value of -100% the bar is being pushed up in the viewport, to a point where it becomes invisible.

Answer (score 0):

To move it to right, when you use `position:fixed` you should use `right:0`.

(In the below code I use the name of social media)

To layout your `a` tags, it's better to use `display:flex`, flex layout is the best way to layout your items on the page.

```css
.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
/*   top: -100%; */
  right:0;
  /*-webkit-transform: translateY(50%); //I comment this code to show element on result box. 
  -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: translateY(50%);*/
}

.icon-bar a {
/*   display: block;
  position: static; */
  display:flex; 
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(196, 44, 44);
}

.twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-bar">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="twitter">twitter</a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com//" target="_blank" class="instagram">instagram</a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in//" target="_blank" class="linkedin">linkedin</a>
  <div>
```

To learn more about `position` these links will help you:

> [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

> [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

About `flex layout`, you can read:

> [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

> [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, it kinda works now but its still not to the most right can i just change it via putting the right:50; or smthn?

Comment: Do you want to align the icons (text) to the right?